# What's the closest airport to the Flatiron District and Chelsea neighbourhood in NY?

Tags: airports, airport-transfer, new-york-city

There are three airports so I wanted to know which one is the closest to the Flatiron and Chelsea? Also, what the fastest way to get to each neighbourhood from the airport?

Comment: Closest or Fastest to get to?  And for what destination?

Comment: Closest to each neighbourhood and the fastest way to arrive at each neighbourhood by transportation.

Comment: Destination is the Flatiron District and the second destination is Chelsea.

Comment: possible duplicate of [New York airports: JFK or Newark Liberty International?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3457/new-york-airports-jfk-or-newark-liberty-international)

Comment: By mileage LGA is closest but again depends on where you're going, time of day, and What kind of Transportation you intend to use.

Comment: @Karlson: it's not a duplicate as I'm asking for distances to specific neighbourhoods not NY in general.

Comment: Well, say I land at 4pm and transportation is whichever is fastest.

Comment: Distance to the airport only matters if you are driving and not so much in NYC since the traffic can turn a 1 mile drive into an hour.  Then there is subway, and shuttles and Tunnels on a clear day with little traffic difference between Flatiron and Chelsea being the side of 6th ave you're on I don't see how this would make any difference and the question I linked answers the questions about using 2 major international airports.

Comment: My main question is which airport is closest to the Flatiron?  And, separately which airport is closest to Chelsea?  Not which airport is closest to them both at the same time.  Sorry, I was not clear.

Comment: I asked the question because it matters to me.

Comment: It may matter to you but not to the geography of the location as I stated the difference between Chelsea and Flatiron is the side of 6th ave.

Comment: Oh okay.  I'm slow.  So, both those neighbourhoods are near each other?  Anyway, what I wanted to know I suppose is which airport in general is closest to both and what is the travel time and extra costs to get to each neighbourhood by each mode of transportation.  What is the traffic like at different times of the day?

Comment: That's a different question all in itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a great service provided by [Google](http://maps.google.com/nyc) which is dead on accurate as far as the city is concerned.  The problem with the time you're landing and the time you will be going into the city is the fact that on a weekday this will be a rush hour, so here are the better options:

**JFK**

- Take [Airtrain](http://www.mta.info/mta/airtrain.htm) to the [E Subway Line](http://www.mta.info/nyct/service/pdf/tecur.pdf) in Jamaica and Take E train Manhattan/Downtown direction, which under normal circumstances will take slightly more then an hour to get to 8th Ave 23rd Street

**LaGuardia**

- Sorry no Airtrain available so it will be a [bus to Subway](https://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&dirflg=r&q=Grand+Central+Station,+NYC&z=12&ie=UTF8&hq=http://maps.google.com/help/maps/transit/nyc/mapleft.kml&ll=40.730478,-73.976612&spn=0.102635,0.171318) transfer which could be a pain with luggage but it will drop you off right in between the 2 districts on 23rd and 6th if you take one of the orange lines [F](http://www.mta.info/nyct/service/pdf/tfcur.pdf) or [M](http://www.mta.info/nyct/service/pdf/tmcur.pdf).  F should be faster since it's running express in Queens.

**Newark**  [Options 1 and 2 can be found through this link](https://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&dirflg=r&q=Grand+Central+Station,+NYC&z=12&ie=UTF8&hq=http://maps.google.com/help/maps/transit/nyc/mapleft.kml&ll=40.730478,-73.976612&spn=0.102635,0.171318)

- **Option 1** - Bus to PATH.  Take a bus from Airport to Newark Path Station and then take PATH to Newark changing at Journal Square Station for Path to 33rd street and take it to 23rd street station which is 23rd street and 6th Ave on the border of the districts.
- **Option 2** - Train to Penn Station.  Take Airtrain in Newark to the Newark Airport train station and then take Amtrak or NJ Transit to the New York Penn Station on 34th and 8th Ave, and then either walk a few blocks (they are short) or take [E train](http://www.mta.info/nyct/service/pdf/tecur.pdf) Downtown direction for 1 stop to 23rd Street.
- **Option 3** - Bus.  [Coach USA](http://www.coachusa.com/olympia/ss.newarkairport.asp) provides a shuttle that runs every 15 minutes from each of the terminals and takes 30 - 60 minutes depending on traffic to get you to NY Port Authority Bus Terminal from which you can take [E Train](http://www.mta.info/nyct/service/pdf/tecur.pdf) or walk.

Of course there are always taxis or airlink services such as:

- [Golden Touch](http://www.goldentouchtransportation.com/Common/Services.asp)
- [Airlink NYC](http://www.goairlinkshuttle.com/index.php)
- [Super Shuttle](http://www.supershuttle.com/?SID=googleadwords_newyork)

That you can simply board and they will drop you off where you need to go.  Might be a little more expensive then Public Transportation but easy and more convenient.

As you can see most trips will take about an hour.

Comment: Whoops, never scrolled down before so I just saw this.

Comment: Do you mind telling me which one requires the least transfers?

Comment: @verve Airlink Services.  They will drop you off exactly where you need to go.

Comment: Do you have to book Airlink in advance or can you request one at the airport?

Comment: @verve Easiest way to find out is to check their website.